# Extracting full text from HTML span element with XPath expression

Tags: html, parsing, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I have a HTML tree which looks like this:

```
<div id="RF4FOEQ3OPBEX" data-hook="review" class="a-section review aok-relative"><div 
   <div data-hook="review-collapsed" aria-expanded="false" class="a-expander-content reviewText review-text-content a-expander-partial-collapse-content">
      <span> 
             Text line1. 
             <br>
             Text line2. 
       </span>
```

I am trying to extract all the text from the span with the following XPath expression:

```
//div[@data-hook="review"]//div[@data-hook="review-collapsed"]/span/text()
```

However this approach only returns the first text line until the break? The question is: how would I approach this problem in the correct way in order to extract the full text content of the HTML span tag? I would appreciate any help very much and thank you in advance for the support.

Comment: xpath('//div[@data-hook="review"]//div[@data-hook="review-collapsed"]/span/text()').getall() in scrapy shell

Answer (score 0):

use `//` and `getall` method to get all text inside specific element

`getall` returns list, just `join` it

```
txt = "".join(response.xpath('//div[@data-hook="review"]//div[@data-hook="review-collapsed"]/span//text()').getall())
```